# How to modify compatibility settings for a file through CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, administrator

I have a package that gets distributed to multiple machines including a batch file that moves some files into directories. One of the files that gets moved is an executable (.exe). This exe will be ran on a schedule, once the batch file runs for the first time, and moves files accordingly, it is never used again.

If I right click the .exe file > `Properties` > `Compatibility`, there is an option under `Settings` to run this program as an administrator. The application only seems to work when it is ran as an administrator, so I would like to enable this setting whenever the batch file runs.

Is there a way to modify this setting within a batch or via CMD?

What I continue to find in my search, is how to run cmd as admin, or how to add a runas command to the batch so the batch itself is executed as a admin. Since the batch file is only run at setup, and never again, I need a way to set the settings for the exe itself to run as admin.

Comment: rather will be easier to modify compatibility settings of a shortcut.I'm thinking on this .Here you can find more info about shortcut structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx . But this will require binary editing with `CERTUTIL` or better with a hybrid vbscript/jscript.

Comment: The proposed answer listed above in the question itself (how to code a BAT file...) is not applicable here. I explicitly list that this is not to set the batch file to run as administrator, but how to use a batch file to set an .exe to run  as admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the info provided in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/563841) you can add the full path to the registry key `Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` with the REG command like so:

*Everything should be on one line but for clarity I put each argument on a separate line*

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers"
    /v "c:\full\path\to\your\exe\file.exe"
    /t REG_SZ
    /d "RUNASADMIN"
```

Above command sets the compatibility flag for all users/system wide. If you want to set it only for the current user use HKCU instead of HKLM.

Do note that setting the value in HKLM subtree requires elevation.

This is tested on Win7 but should work on Vista and Win8.

Comment: On Win8, I found to be a ["magical" leading tilde sign](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27041372/2932052), do you know what it means?