# Meaning of the tilde in compatibility settings values of the Windows 8.1 registry

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, admin, compatibility

I tried to figure out how to **manage compatibility settings** for some older programs in an automated way. This Super User question [How can I set the compatibility mode for an executable from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/379375/how-can-i-set-the-compatibility-mode-for-an-executable-from-the-command-line) already helped a lot pointing onto the registry key being used for compatibility settings.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

Sadly, there is **one tiny detail** remaining unanswered so far. I tried to figure out what changes in application's property dialogue does by inspecting the related registry value, and it seemed so simple! But I'm irritated by the tilde char preceding the [known compatibility switches](http://www.verboon.info/2011/03/running-an-application-as-administrator-or-in-compatibility-mode/), for example:

```
~ WINXPSP3
~ MSIAUTO
~ RUNASADMIN WINXPSP3
```

I tried searching the web for it but without success. I found this ~ flag being used in Windows 8.1 (and Windows 8), but not in earlier Windows versions.

Does anyone know more about it?

- When is it used?
- What does it mean?
- Is there any reliable reference?

Comment: The tilde prefix can also be observed on Windows 10. Until now I found nothing that documents this.

Comment: info: similar question here: https://superuser.com/q/1095300/172012

Comment: It's 2024, and the exact meaning of these prefixes still seems to be a mystery. As of Windows 11 the ~ is still being used, although I have one entry which has a $ prefix.

Current list of compatibility flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/compatibility-fixes-for-windows-8-windows-7-and-windows-vista

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the ~ (tilde) is indeed for Windows 8. I've noticed, in similar situations, on Windows 7, the # (hash) character (followed by space).

Comment: Do you know, if omitting `~`, `#` or whatever causes any difference?

Comment: I cannot see a `#` on that place in Windows 7. Omitting the `~` on Windows 8.1 seems to make no difference.